# VBA lines for multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range, border, line

I want multiple borders for the rows B1, E1 and H1. How can I extend the range command without repeating it over and over again?

the code is:

```
 Worksheets("Table1").Range("B1:B29").BorderAround _
 ColorIndex:=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate using Intersect:

```
Sub tgr()

    With Worksheets("Table1")
        Intersect(.Range("1:29"), .Range("B:B,E:E,H:H")).BorderAround , , 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean as you can achieve with Union?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim unionRng As Range
    With Worksheets("Table1")
    Set unionRng = Union(.Range("B1:B29"), .Range("E1:E29"), .Range("H1:H29"))
    End With
    unionRng.BorderAround _
        ColorIndex:=1
End Sub
```

You could shorten to:

```
Public Sub test()
    With Worksheets("Table1")
       Union(.Range("B1:B29"), .Range("E1:E29"), .Range("H1:H29")).BorderAround _
        ColorIndex:=1
    End With
End Sub
```